# A question about rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ is ring with unit and $a$ is a nonzero element of the ring. If there are two distinct elements $b,c$ such that $ab=ac=1$, show that there are infinite elements $x$ in $R$ such that $ax=1$.

Comment: Is the ring assumed to be commutative?

Comment: Obviously not, @ajotatxe, as then a left inverse = right inverse and thus $\;a\;$ is a unit and there is no question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the elements

$$x_n:=b+\left(1-ca\right)a^n\;,\;\;n=1,2,3,...$$

First, we have that

$$ax_n=ab+(a-aca)a^n=1+(a-a)a^n=1$$

Second, assume $\;n>m\;$ and

$$x_n=x_m\implies(1-ca)a^n=(1-ca)a^m\implies (1-ca)a^{n-m}=1-ca\;\text{(why?)}\implies$$

$$\left[(1-ca)a^{n-m-1}+c\right]a=1$$

and this would mean $\;a\;$ has a left inverse and it is thus a unit so $\;b=c\;$, contradiction.

We thus get $\;\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;$ is an infinite set of right inverses of $\;a\;$ .

Comment: Thanks @HagenvonEitzen. This is a more or less known theorem by Kaplansky.